# What is 'cash considerations'?

Tags: basketball, trade

I've seen quite a few trades in the NBA go by as 'Player X for cash considerations'.

But what is, actually, [cash considerations](https://ftw.usatoday.com/2017/06/portland-trail-blazers-twitter-cash-considerations-rockets-trade-nba)? Is there any obligations to the team that gave 'cash considerations' or its just a fancy way of saying 'we traded the player for literally cash'?

Comment: Have you read this [article](https://www.sportskeeda.com/basketball/what-cash-considerations-nba#:~:text=Cash%20considerations%20in%20the%20NBA%20are%20exactly%20what%20they%20sound,the%20recipient%20team's%20salary%20cap.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cash considerations is a fancy way of saying 'literal cash' with the caveat that it does not count toward the receiving team's salary cap.

The motivation to do this type of trade is:

- to obtain draft picks
- to obtain rights to a particular player (to be drafted or under contract)
- to use as a bargaining chip to match salaries or take on salary

[Article](https://www.sportskeeda.com/basketball/what-cash-considerations-nba#:%7E:text=Cash%20considerations%20in%20the%20NBA%20are%20exactly%20what%20they%20sound,the%20recipient%20team%27s%20salary%20cap) from [jros](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/28205/what-is-cash-considerations?noredirect=1#comment37859_28205):

> Cash considerations in the NBA are exactly what they sound like –
> actual money offered to teams as part of a deal. The only difference
> here is that cash considerations do not count towards the recipient
> team's salary cap.